Idiosyncratic risk calculation - Advanced Portfolio Management (Giuseppe Paleologo)
I'm struggling with the walkthrough of a calculation within this text. For anyone with the book it's an example from section 3.4.2. I will go through the steps here and show where I am getting lost - any help appreciated!
We are given this table below



Field
SYF
WMT
SPY




Beta
1.2
0.7
1


Daily Market Vol (%)


1.4


Daily Idio Vol (%)
1.2
0.5
0


Net Market Value
10M
5M
10M



We are then given the formula below
$$
PNL_{port} = (NMV_{SYF}\times\beta_{SYF}+ NMV_{WMT}\times\beta_{WMT}+NMV_{SPY}\times\beta_{SPY})m+ (NMV_{SYF}\times\epsilon_{SYF}+NMV_{WMT}\times\epsilon_{WMT}+NMV_{SPY}\times\epsilon_{SPY})
$$
I have no problem here.
We then are given:
$$
\text{(porftolio market volality = (portfolio dollar beta)}\times\text{(market volatility)}
$$
$$
\text{25.5M}\times1.4\% = \\\$36K
$$
This is where my first problem lies, as to me that number should be ~360k. As usual I expect somehow this is my mistake and will carry on.
The next step is the idio variance
we are given
$$
\text{(portfolio idio variance)} = (NMV_{SYF}\times vol_{SYF})^2+(NMV_{WMT}\times vol_{WMT})^2+(NMV_{SPY}\times vol_{SPY})^2
$$
Therefore:
$$
\text{(portfolio idio volatility)} = \sqrt{(10\times1.2)^2+(5\times0.5)^2}=\\\$122K
$$
no problems here.
Then we get the total vol as
$$
\text{(portfolio total vol)} = \sqrt{36^2+122^2}=\\\$127K
$$
barring my issues with the 36k vs 360k i mentioned before, no problems.
we are then told about tracking error and how this will be
$$
\\\$122k\times\sqrt{252}\approx\\\$1.9M
$$
So far, excluding hte 36k vs 360k again i am absolutely fine with whats going on here and how its been explained to me.
The Problem
The section then stops, and we open up the new chapter with the following
"we had a Portfolio with a large amount of market risk, but we also have $6.7M of idiosyncratic risk coming from SYF and WMT."
Where is this $6.7M number coming from?

The author admitted on $\mathbb{X}$ (feeling fancy for using Latex on this) that this is a typo and that your reasoning is correct. See this post which was submitted by a user a couple of weeks ago. A second edition of the book will follow at some point in the future.
